# Excel - can you setup a certain worksheet to open when the spreadsheet is first opened?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, spreadsheet, vbscript

Hoping someone can help, I have a spreadsheet that I need to open at a certain page, everytime when opened eg.. an index page.

I have the Vb code and works offline but I have since found out this will not work if I am sharing this online.

Is it still possible to set a landing page, so to speak, with excel online?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: We generally prefer that questions that are asking about code show us the code that the asker already has, especially if it does *part* of what you want.  This decreases the likelihood of answerers posting information that you already know.

Answer (score 0):

The sub shown below will trigger any time the workbook is opened:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 

End Sub
```

You can use this bit of code to change to another worksheet:

```
Worksheets(sheetname).Activate
```

where sheetname = the name of the sheet or the index number. If you combine both bits of code you should be able to accomplish what you are after.

As far as "working online", that really depends on your online security settings. For any .xlsm workbook to run you need to enable it upon opening as well as have the workbook be "trusted".

Comment: Thank you for your replies, @ Eric F I have used this code successfully on excel offline mode, however it unfortunately won't work for excel online, which is my main use.

Comment: For a little more context I use excel on Office 365 onedrive, the spreadsheet works fine but wont open to the sheet I would like as the front page, you had mentioned enable when openeing, please can you advise a little further on this?